# C# Метод XmlDocument.Load (String)

Tags: c#, xml

Сделал авто обновление службы посредством чтения версии из xml документа на сайте.
Поставил по таймеру считывать каждую минуту (для теста).
Служба зависает после второго тика.
Догадываюсь, то что она не может второй раз загрузить XmlDocument.Load (String), т.к он уже открыт. Как закрыть его?

Comment: Отладчик молчит

Comment: Где код? Выполнение точно попадает второй раз в этот метод? точку останова поставьте, проверьте. Какой таймер используете?

Comment: а если в Load передать не String а к примеру Filestream который примет String, FileStream обернуть в using, вызовится Dispose(), или вариант GC.Collect().

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, дело не в xmldocument.load..
Просто заметил этот баг после того как добавил его..

Comment: Чтобы отладчик заговорил, попробуйте его пытать. Натыкайте точек останова вокруг кода, который загружает документ, пройдите этот кусок в пошаговом режиме. Он у вас может зависать на банальном ожидании ответа от сервера.

Answer (score 0):

XmlDocument.Load закрывает файл сразу после его загрузки.
Следующий код к ошибкам не приводит.

```
XmlDocument t = new XmlDocument();
            t.Load(@"test.xml");
            t.Load(@"test.xml");
            t.Load(@"test.xml");
```

Гарантированно "убить" объект можно так:

```
t = null;
GC.Collect();
```

Но проблема явно в чем-то другом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Действительно вы правы, сейчас долго пытался отладить, ошибки никакой не выдает. Убрал весь функционал в службе, кроме запуска по таймеру, гарантированно перестает работать таймер через 45-50 секунд

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, создал простое консольное приложение - в нем работает все отлично. В службе же вот такая фигня

Comment: Таймер использую из System.Threading

Comment: То есть таймер исправно запускает приложение 3 раза(3 тика на данный момент), естественно, если оно уже не запущено. На 4 раз уже не запускается ничего..

Тот же самый код в консольном приложении работает стабильно. разницы в коде между консольном приложении и службой сейчас нет(убрал весь функционал временно)

Comment: public void Timer()
        {
            int num = 0;
            TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(Start);
            Timer Timer = new Timer(tm, num, 0, 15000);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, проблема была действительно в другом, почему то таймер из Threading ломался спустя минуту, заменил его на таймер из Timers и все заработало как надо.